# Using the datetime to perform timedelta function that prints total second in 24 hour period

Tags: python-3.x

Input: 1

Expected: 86480.0

from datetime import timedelta
def get_second(n):

return n.seconds, n.seconds // 3600, (n.seconds // 60) % 60

get_secoond(n)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `timedelta`'s `.total_seconds()` method, you can do:

```py
from datetime import timedelta 

def get_second(n=1):
    s = timedelta(days=n).total_seconds()
    return s, s//3600, (s//60)%60

get_second() # returns (86400.0, 24.0, 0.0)
```

Note that total seconds returns a `float`, not `int`
(Such a simple calculation could also be performed without using the timedelta at all, if input is only in terms of days :

`get_seconds = lambda n=1: (86400*n, int(24*n), int(1440*n)%60)`